# Specifying a hostheader binding in docker

Tags: docker, dns

I have a machine where 2 docker containers are running

Both bind to port 80.

I have specified 2 DNS entries on our DNS server that point to the machine where the containers are running.

Is there a way to bind each container to one of the domain names specified in the DNS server? I know I can have a nginx in front of it, but is there also something in docker I can use?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. You have a couple options:

1. Put a load balancer in front and route requests to different ports:

   - load balancer -> App #1 on Port 8080
   - load balancer -> App #2 on Port 8081
2. Run a NGINX / HAProxy container and map that container to port 80 on the host and use the overlay networking to route traffic from the proxy container to the application containers. The applications will then not map their exposed ports to the host and let dock randomly assigned ports.